# Input numbers until -1 is inputed

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `vector<vector<int>>` and I want to put data into it. I should input the numbers until the first member of a row is `-1` and `-1` also delimits the data every `vector<int>` should hold. For example:

---

```
The contents of vector<vector<int>>
1 1 1 0 0 1 -1 // -1 indicates the end of input for vector<int> number 1
1 1 0 1 -1 // vector<int> number 2
-1  // indicates the end of input from the console
```

---

My application crashes after the first inputted line and I don't know why? Any ideas how to fix it? The code is below:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<vector<int>> waiters;
   int n=0;    

   while(true)
   {
      vector<int> temp;
      while(n!=-1)
      {
        cin>>n;
        temp.push_back(n);
      }
      if(temp.front()== -1)
        break;
      else
        waiters.push_back(temp);        
   }
    for(int i=0;i<waiters.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<waiters.at(j).size();j++)
        cout<<waiters.at(i).at(j)<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you're using `n` even though you haven't assigned a value yet at `while n!=-1`. Furthermore `temp.front()` might execute even though your vector is still empty.

Comment: @Lanting That's not really a problem in this case.

Comment: While it _might_ not be _the_ problem it most certainly is _a_ problem.

Comment: @pesho Yes it is: local variables aren't initialized so reading them is Undefined Behaviour. One posibility is that while doesn't execute and then you to temp.front() on an empty vetor => crash

Comment: another problem is in print second for: should be `for(j = 0, j < waiters.at(i).size(); j++) instead of `at(j)`

Comment: You really ought to step through this in a debugger before posting code to Stack Overflow, then the problems would be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that after a complete line has been entered `n` is never reset to a default value and still contains `-1`. On the next iteration this causes the inner `while` loop to be skipped and `temp.front()` to be called on an empty vector, which is undefined behavior. The following updates should get you back on track.

```
while(true)
{
    vector<int> temp;
    while(n!=-1)
    {
        cin>>n;
        temp.push_back(n);
    }
    n = 0; // RESET n to a default value

    // Add additional check just to be sure.
    if(temp.size() == 0 || temp.front()== -1)
      break;

    waiters.push_back(temp);        
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct: it will result in undefined behavior (and an endless loop) if there is anything unexpected in the input.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that you're trying to do too much in a
single function.  You really need two functions:

```
std::vector<int>
parseLine( std::istream& source )
{
    std::vector<int> results;
    int value;
    while ( source >> value && value != -1 ) {
        results.push_back( value );
    }
    return results;
}
```

and then:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>
getWaiters( std::istream& source )
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> results;
    std::vector<int> line = parseLine( source );
    while ( !line.empty() ) {
        results.push_back( line );
        line = parseLine( source );
    }
    return results;
}
```

You'll notice that this avoids the clumsiness of having to break
out of a loop.

In general, if you find you have to break out of a loop, it's a
sign that you've not got the algorithm right, or that you're
trying to do too much in the loop.  Similarly, nested loops,
when not dealing with mathematical matrices, are also a symptom
of this.

Finally: I might add that this type of input format is rather
unnatural.  More typically, you'd use lines as delimiters
between the entries, and end of file as the final entry.